# How to properly add new directives to a directive during its definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a major problem with dynamic directives withing angularjs.

I'm trying to add new directives to a directive during its definition through an object:

```
compile: function () {
    return {
      pre: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        // in this case cbAttrs is an object {cbSuggest: true, cbDatepicker: true}, for example
        scope.objects = JSON.parse(iAttrs.cbAttrs);
        if (!iAttrs.compiled) {
          angular.forEach(scope.objects, function(props) {
            for (var prop in props) {
              iAttrs.$set(prop, (typeof props[prop] === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(props[prop]) : props[prop]));
            }
          });
          iAttrs.$set('dataCompiled', true);
          $compile(iElement)(scope);
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

I've managed to make it work this way. But honestly I really don't feel is the right way of doing and I can't understand why I have to compile the element during the PRE compiling stage of the directive.

And if I add it this way, the input will behave oddly, for example: trying to move left inside the input and then deleting a letter will make the cursor go right to the end of the input.

I've tried it within the link function, and it will generate the same exact behavior for the input:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.objects = JSON.parse(attrs.cbAttrs);

    if (!attrs.compiled) {
      angular.forEach(scope.objects, function(props) {
        for (var prop in props) {
          attrs.$set(prop, (typeof props[prop] === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(props[prop]) : props[prop]));
        }
      });
      attrs.$set('dataCompiled', true);
      $compile(elem)(scope);
    }
  }
```

Honestly I don't know what else to do. I've seen the comment with the template example, but I don't want to set the return element hard coded.

Plunker with both problems: http://plnkr.co/edit/tbQubTMarjxB8ogzhtey?p=preview
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/Lwktcyu7/

Comment: a simple demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or jsfiddle.net that replicates problem would help. Also to clarify, subject says "add new directives" but I think it should say "add attributes"?

Comment: I will create a simple demo, thanks for the heads up. But even if we are talking about attributes it's still a directive

Comment: It's a little hard to follow exactly what you are trying to do. Could be more clear? Are you saying that you have a directive that checks a property of the parent scope and if truthy adds a second directive to the same element? Is there a reason the directive is on an input in your example? Is there a reason the directives cannot be nested?

Comment: Well, let me try to break it down for you:

the directive is an input, but I recieve the input configuration through a json. the input itself exists on a template, and it is generated through a repeater on that template.

What im trying to basically do, is configure the attributes/directives to be added to that input dynamically through the config json.

Point is, I came to that "fix" of the compiled attr because otherwise You will generate a compile loop. What Im simply trying to do is add new attributes before angular compile my directive, so I can bind new directives dynamically.

Comment: interestingly the cursor issue doesn't exist in firefox. Here's a demo that might help you. Uses `template:function()` to replace the input and adds attributes from JSON also. The cursor problem dissapears  http://plnkr.co/edit/edi1A7kVhbO5MBhz9ZZU?p=preview

Comment: Interesting approach. It works kinda fine, but still looks a bit wrong, doesnt it?

So I should return the element from the template function, didn't know that as well.

Comment: In your code you use `link:` which is a postLink function (in fact [even `post:` works](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/Lwktcyu7/)). It seems you don't have a problem? I can't imagine the use case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i managed to solve all the issues:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  terminal: true,
  priority: 1000,
  compile: function () {
    return {
      post: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        var attrs = $interpolate(iAttrs.cbAttrs);
        attrs = JSON.parse(scope.$eval(attrs));

        angular.forEach(attrs, function(attr){
          for(var prop in attr) {
            iElement.attr(prop, (typeof attr[prop] === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(attr[prop]) : attr[prop]));
          }

        });

        iElement.removeAttr('data-cb-attrs');
        $compile(iElement)(scope);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Basically I use terminal to prevent all the compilation to keep running, add the attributes I need, then remove the directive attribute and compile it.